# Show that the tangents at the extremities of chord of the cardioid through pole are perpendicular.

Tags: calculus, geometry

> Using Differential Calculus, show that the tangents drawn at the extremities of any chord of the cardioid $r=a(1+\cos{\theta})$ which passes through the pole are perpendicular to each other.

Please help me to understand the exact figure of the problem.

[image]

If the above fig is correct, please help me to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For  curves $\mathcal C$ with polar equation $\rho=f(\theta)$, there's a standard formula for the angle $V$ of the tangent line at the point $M$ with polar coordinates $\theta, f(\theta)$ with the polar radius:
$$\tan V=\frac{\rho(\theta)}{\rho'(\theta)}.$$
So, if we denote $N$ the point with coordinates $(\theta+\pi, f(\theta+\pi))$ and $V_1$ the angle of the tangent line at $N$ with its polar radius, these tangent lines will be perpendicular if and only if $V_1=V\pm\frac\pi2$, i.e. if and only if 
$$\tan V\tan V_1=-1\iff\rho(\theta)\rho(\theta+\pi)=-\rho'(\theta)\rho'(\theta+\pi).$$

For  the present curve, this translates as
$$a^2(1+\cos\theta)(1-\cos\theta)=a^2\sin^2\theta$$
which results from well known formulae  of mid-school…

Answer (score 2):

For all polar curves, $$x=r\cos\theta,\\y=r\sin\theta$$

We can therefore get, by differentiation, a standard expression for the gradient:$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\sin\theta+r\cos\theta}{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\cos\theta-r\sin\theta}$$

For the curve $r=a(1+\cos\theta)$, we have $$\frac{dr}{d\theta}=-a\sin\theta$$

With a couple of lines of simplification, we get $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\cot\left(\frac{3\theta}{2}\right)$$

Now the line joining the pole to a point $(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ has gradient $\tan\theta$.

Therefore, two points given by $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ which are collinear with the pole are connected by the relationship $$\tan\theta_1=\tan\theta_2\implies\theta_1=\theta_2+n\pi$$

In this case we can set $\theta_2=\theta_1+\pi$

Therefore the gradient at $\theta_2$ is$$-\cot\left(\frac 32(\theta_1+\pi)\right)$$

This simplifies to $$\tan\left(\frac{3\theta}{2}\right)$$

Hence, by product of gradients being $-1$, the tangents are perpendicular.